# What is the Goblin Mech's weakness?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

When the Goblin Mech first enters on the throne room, he quite obviously spins around and shows that he has a coal furnace on his back. That makes me think this is a centerpiece in how to defeat him.

I haven't had a problem brute-forcing my way through the level by just piling damage on him, but I haven't tried on any difficulty higher than medium yet. I imagine I'll need to take advantage of his weakness on hard and insane if I plan on succeeding.

What is this boss's weakness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Dungeon Defenders](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Mech) wikia,

> Like all bosses, the Goblin Mech has a weakness. By having one player distract the Goblin Mech, another player can attack it from behind. When the gate behind the Goblin Mech opens up, the Goblin Mech will take double damage.

Comment: Flanking bonus!

Comment: Will it take double damage from ground attacks as well, or only attacks that actually hit the small opening that opens up?